# Add UIBarButtonItem to UIToolbar programmatically?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Here's what I need.

I have a free version and a paid version of my app. When the paid version loads, I need 3 UIBarButtons on my UIToolBar. When the Free version loads I need 4 UIBarButtons. On the far right barButton, I need the tint Blue, while the rest are default black. And I'm assuming the flexible space between them to even them out. I've tried doing this through IB, but I can't seem to get it to work with the spacing correct. As you can see, the bottom toolbar with 3 buttons are not spaced evenly with the toolbar. (I would like to do this programmatically)

[image]

[image]

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION


#else

[buyButton removeFromSuperview];

#endif
```

Comment: can i have some code for more clarity

Comment: Button looked so beautiful <3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
[toolbar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

// create an array for the buttons
NSMutableArray* BarbuttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

// create a clearAll button
UIBarButtonItem * clearAllButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear All" 
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                             target:self
                             action:@selector(clearAllAction:)];

clearAllButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[BarbuttonsArray  addObject:clearAllButton];
[clearAllButton release];


 // create a calculate button
 UIBarButtonItem *calculateButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Calculate" 
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(calculateButton:)];
calculateButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[BarbuttonsArray  addObject:calculateButton];
[calculateButton release];


// create a settingButton
UIBarButtonItem *settingButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Setting" 
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                             target:self
                             action:@selector(settingButton:)];
settingButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[BarbuttonsArray  addObject:settingButton];
[settingButton release];


 // create a buyNowButton

UIBarButtonItem *buyNowButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Buy Now" 
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                          target:self
                          action:@selector(buyNowButton:)];
buyNowButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[BarbuttonsArray  addObject:buyNowButton];
[buyNowButton release];


 // put the BarbuttonsArray in the toolbar and release them
[toolbar setItems:BarbuttonsArray  animated:NO];
[BarbuttonsArray  release];

// place the toolbar into the navigation bar
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
[toolbar release];


//before using these lines of code you have to alloc and make the property of   UINavigationController in your appDelegate
```

Try to use this may help you

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it to show up, however this pushes my view down and puts the toolbar at the top, I need this on top of the view and at the bottom.

Comment: Ok, I got the UIToolBar to show at the bottom by changing some code you had. But there should be some flexible spaces between the buttons so when I remove one, the buttons even out on the toolbar.

Comment: Flexible spaces are not there?

Comment: i suggest one thing, just put the FlexibleSpace barbutton item between every barbuttons. And make condition for BUYNow button if its LITE_VERSION it should not be added to BarButtonItems array.

Answer (score 0):

First add buy button on your toolbar. bind and synthesize.

```
if(AppPaid) { 
    NSMutableArray *items = [YourToolBar.items mutableCopy];
    [items removeObject:yourBuyButton];
    YourToolBar.items = items;
    [items release];
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that code. I couldn't get the "YourToolBar" To not have an error. I'm still new to this.

Comment: I've added my code above, everything was through IB so the IBOutlets are the only other thing. You can see how many buttons I have. I guess if you could explain how I would "hookup" the "YourToolBar" part of your code, I think that's where my issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

```
IBOutlet UITabBarItem * item1;
```

like this create 4 items... give link to your xib so that we can hide required `tabbarItem` when ever you want... I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Add the buy button to your toolbar by default, and tag it with some unique value (say -1), and then at runtime you can remove it from the toolbar like so:

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    //Dont need to do anything, view is set up as lite version by default
#else

    NSArray *elements = toolBar.items;
    NSMutableArray *newElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[elements count]];

   for ( UIBarItem *item in elements )
   {
        if ( item.tag != -1 )
        {
            //Item is not the buy button, add it back to the array
            [newElements addObject:item];
        }
    }

    [toolBar setItems:newElements];

#endif
```

This is some code I use in one of my apps already to replace an item that is tagged in IB with `-1` with a specific button at runtime, depending on which view is on display